# Solve $(x+y \log y)y\, \mathrm{d}x=(y+x \log x)x \,\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Solve the differential equation $$(x+y \log y)y \,\mathrm{d}x=(y+x \log x)x \,\mathrm{d}y$$

My try: put $x=e^t$ and $y =e^w$: we get

$$(e^t+w e^w)e^w e^t \,\mathrm{d}t=(e^w+te^t)e^we^t\,\mathrm{d}w\implies
(e^t+we^w)\,\mathrm{d}t=(e^w+te^t)\,\mathrm{d}w$$

Any clue here?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: Yes it's an implicit function

Comment: Just an observation: by symmetry $y(x) = x$ works.

Comment: Yes but y=x only in first quadrant

Comment: Yes sure, because both $y$ and $x$ must be positive.

Comment: But $x^y=y^x$ also satisfies but unable to prove

Comment: We can verify that $x^y=y^x$ satisfies the equation using $y=-\frac{x}{\log (x)} W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function

Comment: Did this differential equation come from some other problem? If so, it would help greatly if you can include that problem, especially if it's a physical one. It can give some surprising insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have the following differential equation:

> $$(x+y \log y)y \,\mathrm{d}x=(y+x \log x)x \,\mathrm{d}y$$

Rearranging the terms, we get:

$$\implies xy\mathrm{d}x+y^{2}\log(y)\mathrm{d}x=xy\mathrm{d}y+x^{2}\log(x)\mathrm{d}y$$
$$\implies-x^{2}\log(x)\mathrm{d}y+xy\mathrm{d}x=-y^{2}\log(y)\mathrm{d}x+xy\mathrm{d}y$$
$$\implies x(-x\log(x)\mathrm{d}y+y\mathrm{d}x)=y(-y\log(y)\mathrm{d}x+x\mathrm{d}y)$$

Dividing both sides by the term $x^{2}y^{2}$,  we get:

$$\implies \frac{(-x\log(x)\mathrm{d}y+y\mathrm{d}x)}{xy^2}=\frac{(-y\log(y)\mathrm{d}x+x\mathrm{d}y)}{x^{2}y}$$
$$\implies \left(-\frac{1}{y^2}\mathrm{d}y\right)\log(x)+\left(\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right)\frac{1}{y}=\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x\right)\log(y)+\left(\frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y\right)\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\implies \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\log(x)+\mathrm{d}\left(\log(x)\right)\frac{1}{y}=\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\log(y)+\mathrm{d}\left(\log(y)\right)\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\implies \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{y}\log(x)\right)=\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log(y)\right)$$

Integrating both sides, we get:

$$\implies \int \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{y}\log(x)\right)=\int \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log(y)\right)$$

We get the solution as: $$\color{darkblue}{\frac{1}{y}\log(x)=\frac{1}{x}\log(y)+C}$$

Where $C$ is the integration constant. This is the ***implicit solution***.

**Edit:** As shown by @[Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici), the solution can be converted to an explicit one using [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The solution is as follows:

Rearranging the above equation, we get:

$$\implies \frac{x}{y}\log(x)=\log(y)+Cx$$

Taking exponential of both sides, we have:

$$\implies \exp\left({\frac{x}{y}\log(x)}\right)=\exp\left(\log(y)\right)\exp\left(Cx\right)$$

$$\implies \exp\left({\frac{x}{y}\log(x)}\right)=y\exp\left(Cx\right)$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{x}{y}\log(x)$, we have:

$$\implies \frac{x}{y}\log(x)\exp\left({\frac{x}{y}\log(x)}\right)=x\exp\left(Cx\right)\log(x)$$

If we consider $\frac{x}{y}\log(x)$ as $u$, the above equation reduces to $ue^u=K$ and can be represented by Lambert $W$ function as $u=W(K)$, so we have:

$$\implies \frac{x}{y}\log(x)=W\left(x\exp\left(Cx\right)\log(x)\right)$$
$$\implies \color{darkgreen}{y=\frac{x \log (x)}{W\left(x e^{Cx} \log (x)\right)}}$$

where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. This is the **explicit solution**.

Comment: perfect, clean and well formated answer

Comment: Nice solution, for sure ! $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici and Matěj, Thank you :)

Comment: May be, you could add to your good answer that the final solution is $$y=\frac{x \log (x)}{W\left(x e^{c x} \log (x)\right)}$$. where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To make it's representation explicit ?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be nice. I shall delete my comment in a few seconds to make you feeling more comfortable. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, no need to delete your comment, after all it's your idea and your comment is the proof of that :). It's a really nice idea, thank you I'll add that.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici also I am a bit stupid when it comes to Lambert (it's totally new to me) function, so I was hoping if you could show how to get to the final result so that I can add it (or you may edit my answer). Meanwhile I am trying to know more about it and how to convert something to Lambert, till now I could only see that it represents the inverse of a function.

Comment: Try to learn about Lambert function. It allows to solve explicitly so many problems. Just search of this site **Lambert function**; 2277 posts ! It heps to solve a huge number of problems in mathematics, physics, chemistry, biochemistry and so on. Just for your curiosity, Euler and Lambert worked together.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sure, thank you. I'll add the final solution after I understand how to derive it. Thanks for the advice, it's a really nice way to convert something implicit to explicit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have added the solution :)